# Excel - What function to achieve this task

Tags: excel, function, design-patterns, offset

I have a forecast in row 2.  The item has to be growing for a total of 5 weeks, as denoted by Column B.  This time can vary.
As a result the product takes up space for 5 weeks, as shown by rows 3 to 7.  I have them summed the total space taken in Row 8.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I could automatically go from the Forecast line in Row 2, to the Total line in Row 8 please?  To save the manual work of adding in each line, then adding them up.

Even a suggestion of an excel function would be much appreciated.  I have tried and my lack of knowledge isn't helping. Thanks

[image: Example problem]

Comment: How do you calculate the Total Space for weeks from wk10 to the end?

Comment: Hi David, the total space taken for Week 10 is 190. As the plants take 5 weeks to grow, the week 11 dispatch plants (25) will be taking up space to grow, and so will the week 12 dispatch plants (53) taking up space etc, etc.  Sorry if I have misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks, @Student201, my question is not about the number, but about how did you get that number? How do you calculate, explained in natural language, no need for excel formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution that use the INDRECT function to get a dynamic array of the product quantities that need space in a given week.

In C3: `=LET(startWeek,MATCH(C1,$C$1:$R$1,0)+3,endWeek,startWeek+$B$2-1,range,INDIRECT("R2C"&startWeek&":"&"R2"&"C"&endWeek,FALSE),TRANSPOSE(range))`

Copy formula in C3 across to D3 through R3.

In C13: `SUM(C3#)`

Copy formula in C13 across to D13 through R13.

This would give you something that looks like this:
[image]

You can of course combine the formulas in C3 and C13 and just get one row with the total for each week:

In C3: `=LET(startWeek,MATCH(C1,$C$1:$R$1,0)+3,endWeek,startWeek+$B$2-1,range,INDIRECT("R2C"&startWeek&":"&"R2"&"C"&endWeek,FALSE),SUM(range))`

Again, copy this from C3 across to D3 through R3.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jakob, thank you very much for taking the time to formulate a detailed answer.  I was hoping to be able to go straight from the Forecast in Row 2, to the Space totals, without the need to have those 5 lines in between.  
As otherwise would have to add all these lines for each different product in my document, 3, 4, 5, 6 lines etc.  I probbably wasn't clear in my question...  Maybe impossible to go straight from the forecast line to the space totals in one go!

Comment: You're welcome! In order to get the total without the rows inbetween use SUM(...) instead of TRANSPOSE(...) in the first formula. I added this to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks Jakob, have done so now, only have Office 2010 on my laptop so had to wait until I had access to a more up to date Excel to test.

Comment: Awesome Student201. In case you don't have a newer version of Excel on your laptop, you can always work with (most of) the new features in the Excel Web version available from http://office.com and it is super easy to share with collaborators. For example, you can see the suggested solution to your forecast example right here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmZt2yR0G2fmu-85Svb0uyR3qM3p8Q?e=QHd50n